# Is there a possibility to search for mathematical symbols in question titles?

Tags: support, search

So here is my question,

First of all It is my first question on Metha so I am not sure if am allowed to ask this here if not please tell me and I will immediately delete the question. Furthermore I am pretty sure someone somewhen asked a similar question but I was not able to find it...

I was wondering if there is a possibility to search for mathematical symbols written in Latex code in MastE. To be more precise, for example if I am looking for something concerning $L^p$-spaces, is it possible to look somehow for "(dollar) L^p (dollar)" in the titles of already asked questions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See also: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12993/what-is-the-best-way-to-search-for-a-math-equation-on-the-internet and meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6180/search-queries-involving-symbols-and-or-tex (You will find further links there.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just see that there are many comments maybe answering my question.

Comment: For your specific problem you could try to look in questions tagged ([tag:lp-spaces]). You could also try to search for ["L_p" site:math.stackexchange.com](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22L_p%22+site:math.stackexchange.com) on Google.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Very smart idea looking over google! Thx!

Comment: BTW according to this answer http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6855/i-cant-search-on/7103#7103 the built-in search engine should respect dollars and special symbols. I am also reposting a link from my first comment (somehow I managed to omit "http" part, so it is not clickable): http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6180/search-queries-involving-symbols-and-or-tex